# Loss in current while voltage remains

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-motor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe3wMu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The schematic shows an attempt to amplify the signal coming from my chip to help fully saturate the base of the TIP29. All in all, the voltage I get when everything is running, is perfect across the board.
;However, the motors are finicky. Though they receive all the voltage, the current going to them is very poor. The motors have virtually no resistance so they need to pull almost all the current to get to full power.

Increased voltage to the amp was far more helpful than increased voltage to the motors. Naturally I would think to increase the voltage for the amp. The problem is this is a quadcopter. I cant just slap 2 9v batteries in series.

I'm still a student, so my familiarity with part models is not the best. I'm merely using the parts they taught us with. Any help for this would be excellent. I have been wrestling with this problem for months and need some help.

PS: I couldn't find the motor icon in the schematic editor.

Comment: If they're getting "all the voltage" and you're not getting the power out that you need then the back EMF of the motor is restricting the current.  You need more voltage to overcome that, assuming that the motor can handle it.

Comment: I miss spoke. They get acceptable voltage, but not all the voltage. Through the motors is, 3.3v, which I can work with, but the preferred is 3.7v. Using separate power supply's, the odd thing was, increased voltage to the motors did very little while increased voltage to the amp is what helped the most.

Comment: The output of the op-amp connected directly to the base of the BJT is likely to lead to damaging one or the other of those parts.

Comment: Good to know. How should I approach this? Small resistor?

Comment: @ThePhoton It's not good practice, but probably won't cause damage.  Most op-amps have current limit protection and can't put out nearly enough current to damage a TIP29.  To the OP, why not just use a logic level low RDSon FET to switch the motor?

Comment: OP, John D is right, the best solution is probably ditch the op-amp all together and find an appropriate transistor. To do that you need to know the actual current you will drive the motor with.

Answer (score 1):

So, there are a couple problems here:

- You have a gain of 2.25 for your op amp, but your op-amp is powered by +9V and 0V:  you are trying to output 10V but you can't output more than about 7V.  The 7V comes from the fact that under load, your op amp can't actually output voltages at the "rails".  This parameter is under the "output voltage swing" in the datasheet, though I guessed that the 2V from the rails is consistent across voltages, which I'm not positive on.  You can confirm this by looking at what the voltage coming out of the op amp is in your circuit.  In general, it isn't a good idea to drive an op amp to the rails unless you have an op amp specifically designed for that (generally called rail-to-rail op amps).  Sometimes they can latch up (stick at the large voltage out), or they can go negative.
- Your tip29 saturates at 0.7V, so when the transistor is , so best case scenario, you have 3.4V across your motor.  However, I think you aren't actually saturating it.  The Vce(sat) figure in the datasheet is 0.7V, at 1A collector current, and 125mA base current.  That means, if you want to saturate your transistor, you need to source 125mA of current into the base.  Your op amp datasheet says that the short circuit current that the op amp can deliver is 25mA.  Since you can't source enough current, the voltage across the transistor can't get as high as 3.4V.

Now, for the solutions:

The easy one is to replace the tip29 with a "logic level mosfet".  A mosfet can be considered a voltage controlled resistor.  When you change the voltage between the "gate" (analogous to the base of a transistor) and the "source" (analogous to the emitter of a transistor), the resistance between the source and the "collector" (analogous to the collector of a transistor) changes.  A large Vgs (voltage between gate and source) makes a small resistance. The important thing is that MOSFETs have a very high input resistance -- it doesn't really take any current at all to change the voltage of the gate.    Thus, your op amp won't have any trouble driving it.  The "logic level" part tells you that it is turned on by a voltage of around 3-5V.

How much current do you WANT to go through the motor?  This will help you decide on the mosfet to get.

tip29 datasheet: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/ti/tip29.pdf

lm741 datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what we have here, is a failure to saturate. (This is a Steve McQueen movie joke I couldn't resist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=452XjnaHr1A :)

In order to get 3.7 V to the motor, you need a very small \$V_{CE}\$ drop across the transistor, 0.4 V or less. If you measure the voltage across those pins of the transistor when it's running, you can confirm this as the problem.

I believe @JohnD and @ThePhoton are quite correct as to the solution being a different transistor. The TIP29 [datasheet here](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/ti/tip29.pdf) shows a saturation voltage of 0.7 V, and that's with 1A of collector current and 125 mA of base current.

The absolute maximum it looks like you can get out of the LM721 [datasheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) is 25 mA. So I think this circuit is just not going to work for you.

As John and The Photon suggest, a MOSFET is likely to be a good choice since you can find so-called "logic level" devices that will turn on pretty hard with the 5V you have available. When turned on all the way, they look like a low-value resistor (the \$R_{DSon}\$ spec). Here's [an example](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP30N06L.pdf) which might switch as much as 10A before dropping 0.4V. You can probably do a bit better if you look around as you might not need the 60 V \$V_{DS}\$ this device provides.

At that point, you probably don't need the op amp anymore since a logic pin should be able to drive the gate of the MOSFET directly.